# Does nginx add path to all browser requests?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx to reverse proxy some services like Kanboard, PgAdmin, StackStorm, Grafana, etc. Using location /kanboard/ and /pgadmin/ i'm redirected correctly but the page can't import js and css files. Obs: I am using docker for the services and nginx.

I've already tried some proxy_pass params but didn't succeeded.

Nginx config

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

events {}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;

    location /kanboard/ {                              
      proxy_pass http://kanboard;
    }

    location /pgadmin/ {                              
      proxy_pass http://pgadmin;
    }
  }
}
```

Accessing localhost/kanboard i was expected to be redirected to localhost/kanboard/login, but i am redirected to localhost/login.

When i access localhost/pgadmin the js and css files fail to import on the network tab, all the headers are to localhost/static/... instead of localhost/pgadmin/static/...